# Erlang: Is it ok to write application without a supervisor?

Tags: erlang

I don't need a supervisor for some specific application I develop. Is it ok to **not** to use one?

The doc says about the `start/2` that

> "should return {ok,Pid} or {ok,Pid,State} where Pid is the pid of the
>   top supervision"

so I'm not sure if it is OK not to start a supervisor and to return some invalid pid (I tried and nothing bad happened)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning an `{ok, self()}` or something similar works fine until you start doing release upgrades.  At that point, you'll need to use a supervisor with an empty child list.  (The `application` and `supervisor` behaviours don't have colliding callback functions, so you can put both in the same module.)

Just to make sure: you are doing some kind of initialisation in your application module's `start` callback function, right?  If not, you can just remove the `mod` directive from the `.app` file and the callback won't even be called, and thus there will be no supervisor, real or fake.